# Consistent ordering of Ajax results

Tags: ajax, coffeescript, playframework-2.4

I have Coffeescript code running in playframework which builds a table based on several AJAX queries.

```
$ ->
    $.get "/queues", (queues) ->
        $.each queues, (index, queue) ->
            $.get "/queue/" + queue, (html) ->
                $("#queues").append $("<tr>").html html
```

`/queues` returns a list of queue names.
`/queue/name` returns HTML describing queue `name`.
`#queues` is a table, where I display that description.

This all works fine, but since the queries are asynchronous, the append calls are executed in a different order each time, which means that the table contents are randomly reordered every time the query runs.  Since this is providing the current status of a dynamic, the query runs every three seconds.

What is a good way to have the rows be displayed in a consistent order every time?  I have `index`, so I could try adding the data into that row, but if the third query returns first, adding it to row three is not going to work well.

I do not have a strong preference about how the ordering is done, just that it is consistent over multiple loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to force the queries to be sequential. For example, define a recursive function to get the results of one query before making the next one:

```
do_queue = (index, queues) ->
    if index >= queues.length then return
    queue = queues[index]
    $.get "/queue/" + queue, (html) ->
        $("#queues").append $("<tr>").html html
        do_queue(index+1, queue)
```

Then call it like this:

```
$ ->
    $.get "/queues", (queues) ->
        do_queue(0, queues)
```

Comment: Excellent.  That does just what I need.